# HTTPS request from nodejs responds with 503

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, request

I am serving a client frontend from a nodejs server. This client will communicate with an external target server. The target server which I don't own uses Basic authentication. If I send requests to it using postman or the browser they are fine but what I want to achieve is sending the request from the browser to my nodejs server, do some processing there and only after that forward the request from nodejs to the actual server. When I try this, I get a 503 response form the external server.

```
- Client running on my server sends the request to /endpoint/*

- My server receives the request on /endpoint/* and forwards it to https://my.external.server.com/api/*
```

A simplified version of the nodejs server listener

```js
import {Server} from "node:http";
import {request} from "node:https";

function listener(req, res) {
    if (req.url.startsWith("/endpoint")) {
        const options = {
            host: "my.external.server.com",
            method: req.method,
            headers: req.headers,
            path: req.url.replace("/endpoint", "/api"),
            rejectUnauthorized: false, 
        };
        const proxyReq = request(options, proxyRes => {
            res.writeHead(proxyRes.statusCode, proxyRes.headers);
            proxyRes.pipe(res, {end: true});
            return;
        });
        req.pipe(proxyReq, {end: true});
        return;
    }
    // Otherwise serve the client's html
}

new Server(listener).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
```

If the client sends the same exact request to `https://my.external.server.com/api/*` it works.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. Can you show us your _real_ code?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. It is pretty much the same as my real code tho.

Comment: Does it work if you add `delete options.headers.host` before making the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When proxying a request from `localhost` to `my.external.server.com`, you must avoid forwarding the request header `Host: localhost` unchanged if the external server relies on the [`Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header. For example, the `Host` header may be used to find the correct server among many that are reached via the same IP address.

If you `delete options.headers.host` before making the request, the `request` method will automatically set `Host: my.external.server.com` based on the URL it is calling, and the external server gets the value it expects.